# How to connect with privateKey and certificate in Rebex

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, rebex

I have the ssh command:

`$ssh -i cert.pub -i private_rsa user@host.net`

I'm using Rebex.Net.Ssh and I'd like to know how call Login method with Certificate (cert.pub) and PrivateKey (private_rsa), just like command above.

This is possible?

I currently have this code:

`ssh.Login(userName, password, new SshPrivateKey(keyPath, keyPassphase))`

Best regards!

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://www.rebex.net/terminal-emulation.net/features/authentication.aspx#public-key

Comment: Rebex SSH libraries support X.509 certificate authentication. However, from your command line, it looks like you are using OpenSSH's proprietary certificate format (see http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.certkeys), which unfortunately is not compatible withj X.509, and not supported by Rebex libraries.